# shell scripting - get the highest value from an alpha numeric list

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, max, jq

I have the output of a bash script running like such

`{"name":"abc/123","tags":["X-1","X-2","X-3","X-4"....... "X-1099"]}`

I'd like to find the highest value for X in this case `X-1099`. Can someone suggest an approach? Seems like jq might be a start.

So I've made a bit of progress jq '.tags' gives the list of X values

Thanks in advance

Comment: So I've made a bit of progress
`jq '.tags'` gives the list of X values

Comment: You most likely snagged a downvote because you didn't include your attempt in the Q. I'd suggest moving the comment to the Q, so you don't attract any more.  Also, it's generally appreciated if your sample is syntactically valid (in this case, valid JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jq:

```
.tags | max_by(sub("X-";"") | tonumber)
```